# How to change the copy icon when drag any content on page in Edge

Tags: javascript, microsoft-edge

I need to display a customized icon when dragging selected content on webpage. Tried serval ways, but still cannot change the icon displayed by browser.

My Code:

```
<html>
<head>
    <link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.min.js" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function ondragstart(e) {
        }

        function ondragmove(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
        }

        function ondragend(e) {
        }      

        document.addEventListener("dragstart", ondragstart);
        document.addEventListener("dragover", ondragmove);
        document.addEventListener("dragend", ondragend);
    </script>
</head>

<body>    
    Test
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I dont see any code here that even attempts to change anything visually.

Answer (score 0):

```
document.style.cursor = "pointer";
```

Changes the mouse cursor, which is what I assume you are referring to.

Refer to [MDN for more information](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/cursor?v=example), such as available cursors or how to use a custom cursor.